# How to make objects have different names based on the current iteration in the loop?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want my program to read text from a file and create objects with properties read from the file. I have a loop going through the contents of a file and creating objects. But the objects will have the same names. So is there a way to create objects with names based on the iteration of a loop i.e. i=10 so object name is object10, i=15 name is object15 etc.

```cs
long numberOfLines = File.ReadLines(fileName).Count();
for (int i = 2; i <= numberOfLines; i += 2) 
{
    string name = "project " + i.ToString;
    Project <name> = new Project();
}
```

I'd want  to be project although I have no idea how to do it. The only idea I have is to make the project name to be a variable - concatenated "project"+ i but I don't think it's doable

Comment: You will not be able to use these objects anyway because they get "killed" at the end of the scope. Use [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Why is variable name important? Can't you just create the Project and add it to collection like List<Project>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. You can, however, create a dictionary and save the name as you want as a key and assigning the value as the object you created.

```
long numberOfLines = File.ReadLines(fileName).Count();
var projects = new Dictionary<string, Project>();
for (int i = 2; i <= numberOfLines; i += 2) 
{
    projects.Add("project " + i, new Project());
}
```